# Can't install pod in flutter project problem with Firebase/Database

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database, flutter-dependencies

[image]

The version i used firebase_database: ^9.1.7, flutter_geofire: ^2.0.0

Comment: flutter_geofire: ^2.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```
 $ flutter pub add flutter_geofire
```

This will add a line like this to your package's pubspec.yaml:

```
dependencies:
  flutter_geofire: ^2.0.1
```

Comment: no this not working, same issue happen

Answer (score 0):

Try

`pod update`  and then `pod install`

Answer (score 0):

A way I 'reset' pods:

cd ios

mv Podfile podfile-bak

rm -rf Pod*

pod init

mv podfile-bak Podfile

pod install

pod update

cd ..

flutter run

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).